# Visual Studio: how to stop IntelliSense appearing after quote in HTML editor?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

In HTML editor in VS 2013, when I am inside a paragraph and type `'` or `"`, some snippet dropdown appears:

[image: auto IntelliSense after a single-quote]

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

This is probably not a VS-thing but a bug in [WebEssentials](http://vswebessentials.com/). I've reported it to the team.